# How to reduce the height of Autocomplete component of Material UI?

Tags: material-ui

Can anyone help me to reduce the height of Material UI Autocomplete component ? I am trying to use set the height property to 10 or 20 px though the classes property. But it does nothing. Also tried to reduce the height of the Textfield which wrapped by Autocomplete component, but when I tried to reduce the height of the Textfield component through InputProps, then the Items that were to be suggested in Autocomplete area don't display.

Answer (score 13):

I am also customizing the `Autocomplete` component.

To reduce the height, I used the `size` attribute and removed the `label` attribute.

```js
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="standard" size="small" />}
```

Make sure not to override the `params` provided by the Autocomplete component on your TextField component, which already include things like `InputProps`.

You'll probably want to use [Autocomplete's CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css) to achieve all the customizations you're looking for. For example,

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  },
  popupIndicator: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  },
  root: {
    padding: `0 ${theme.spacing(1)}px`,
  },
}))

const AutocompleteWrapper = ({
  value,
  onChange,
  options,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
  <Autocomplete
    classes={classes}
    options={options}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="standard" size="small" />}
  />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the prop ListboxProps:

Like

```
<Autocomplete
  fullWidth
  disableClearable   
  ListboxProps={{ style: { maxHeight: 150 } }}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the input height via the css

```
.MuiInputBase-input {
  height: 1.5rem;
}
```

If you have tags inside - you will also need to set their height, otherwise they will increase their container height

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more idiomatic approach (depending on your use case) is to [limit tags](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#limit-tags) for autocomplete

```
    <Autocomplete
      multiple

      limitTags={2}   <-- THIS

      id="multiple-limit-tags"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      defaultValue={[top100Films[13], top100Films[12], top100Films[11]]}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="limitTags" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @H.Hattab. For anyone using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) here is the example

```
const AutoComplete = styled(Autocomplete)`
  & .MuiInputBase-input {
    height: 1.5rem;
  }
`;
```